# Increment a sequence twice in DB2

Tags: db2, sequence

I need to get the next value of a sequence twice in DB2 (version 9.1).  Rather than executing the following twice:

```
SELECT nextval FOR schema.sequence AS id
FROM dual
```

I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT nextval FOR schema.sequence AS id1,
       nextval FOR schema.sequence AS id2
FROM dual
```

Except the above only increments it once:

```
ID1         ID2        
----------- -----------
        643         643

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Am I forced to just query twice, or is there a way to increment it twice in 1 query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a a little complex, but it works (I verified by running it in DB2 v.9).

```
WITH GENERATED (KEYVAL) AS
(select 1
   from sysibm.sysdummy1
  UNION ALL
 SELECT KEYVAL + 1
   FROM GENERATED
  WHERE KEYVAL < 2)        -- how many you want

SELECT KEYVAL AS INCREMENT_NUMBER, NEXTVAL FOR schema.sequence
  FROM GENERATED;
```

This is some of my favorite code, and it is recursive SQL.  You can do it without the sequence object, and it will just generate several rows of numbers.  I use this sometimes to insert rows of generated test data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a hack, but the following works... I would love to see a cleaner answer though, so please post an answer if you know one!

```
SELECT nextval FOR schema.sequence AS id
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual) temp
```

Which results with:

```
ID         
-----------
        669
        670

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no sequence nor dual table in DB2

Comment: schema.sequence was intended to be a placeholder for a sequence I need to pull from.  dual was intended to be a generic table indicating that I don't care what table I am selecting from, and it actually has meaning in other databases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Answer (score 0):

Just because I'm picking on you Mike :-P, here's another solution:

```
VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR schema.sequence, NEXT VALUE FOR schema.sequence;
```

It will work if you do it as two rows, like here. But if you do it as one row:

```
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR schema.sequence, NEXT VALUE FOR schema.sequence);
```

it will return the same sequence value. :-(